# Where do I get windows 7 software for Virtualbox?

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, sony

I have just got a Sony Xperia phone. I am trying to connect that with the ubuntu OS I have. I was told it would work on ubuntu by the shop assistant..but that was a lie. Ubuntu is very new to me and I am so confused. I have spent the last 6 hours trying to find a way for it to work. I am currently watching this youtube video:http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1DhwS4eZExU and have done everything up to this point at 4:37, the only problem is I don't have the software or drivers for windows 7, this guy downloaded them from a torrent. Does anyone know how I can get what ever I need for this to work? Thank you so much.

Comment: "I was told it would work on ubuntu by the shop assistant". A lie or you lacking knowledge? Oh and a virtualbox is not the way to go. Neither is expecting windows software to help here. Simpel: a phone needs to support MSC and it will work in Ubuntu/Linux.

Answer (score 2):

You can connect your SonyXperia phone to Ubuntu, just you need to do a few settings. At your Sony Xperia phone, go to settings, and then Xperia(tm). Tap on the Connectivity and then USB Connection Method. Choose MSC instead of MTP. You now have the capability to access your SD storage card. You can't access Internal Memory, however.

If you don't have Windows 7 OS software, you have to look for it. You can download using torrent I don't recommend it. Using Virtual Box will not work since Linux couldn't access MTP USB connection. I suggest dual boot instead, if you want.